# Watin throws exception when Attach to IE

Tags: watin

I am using for my Automation framework but I keep getting this error:
  System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
[image]

```
IE newIE = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(new Regex("test.aspx")));
```

What is the cause for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added 'Interop.SHDocVw' reference and make 'Embedded Interop' property to 'False'. Also try to the test with admin rights.

Thanks,

Sham_